# How to run code after Flask send_file() or send_from_directory()

Tags: python, download, flask, werkzeug

I have a Flask-based website where users can download some PDF files.

This is straightforward to implement using Flask's [`send_file()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file) and [`send_from_directory()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory).

For example:

```
@app.route('/downloadreport')
def download_report():
    return send_from_directory(
        '/reports', 
        'my_report.pdf', 
        as_attachment=True)
```

I'd like to perform some logic (let's call it `after_download()`) **AFTER the download is complete**.

I've tried using the [`@after_this_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.after_this_request) hook.  But it looks like `send_file()` runs asynchronously so `@after_this_request` may fire before the file is downloaded.

- For example, if the file is very large, a download may take a while so `@after_this_request` seems to fire while the file is being downloaded.
- It looks from [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file) like `send_file()` uses WSGI's file wrapper to effectuate the download...maybe that's why it's running asynchronously?

Is there a way to call `after_download()` so that it's guaranteed to run after `send_file()` has *completed* sending the file to a user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't. While `send_file` streams the file using Flask when using the dev server, it may (and really should for performance) use the web server (nginx, apache, etc.) and `X-SendFile` in production. Since the web server is beyond the control of the application, you're out of luck.