# Error with send_file using flask in Python

Tags: python, flask, sendfile

I have an application where, through a server, the user needs to download a CSV file and an image that is stored in the same directory as the .py file but it doesn´t work.
Here are my python code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods= ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('result.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
             
            if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Download CSV':
                return send_file('name.csv', as_attachment=True, download_name='name.csv')
                

            elif request.form['submit_button'] == 'Download plot':
                return Flask.send_static_file('static/plot.png', as_attachment=True, download_name='plot.png')
                              
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here are my html code:

```
<div class = 'wrap'>
     
 
    <form method="POST">

        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Download CSV">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Download plot">

    </form>
</div>
```

And here are my directories:

[image]

However, when I try to download it, I get the following error:

[image]

Thank you very much!!! I hope you can help me!

Comment: The error message tells you EXACTLY what you have done wrong.  You need `return send_file(...)`.  And by the way, you have misspelled "Download".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask send\_file not sending file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747258/flask-send-file-not-sending-file)

Comment: @gla3dr I add the return but it doesnt work and with the same error

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks!! I correct the lines and add the return but the same error persists

Comment: Have you printed `request.form['submit_button']` to see what you get?  If it doesn't match either string, you will return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong.

> The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

You are not returning any response from the view function when the request is a POST. The [`send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.send_file) function returns a Response object, that you then need to return from the view function. So, you just need to do

```
                return send_file('name.csv', as_attachment=True, download_name='name.csv')
```

Comment: I have applied the changes but it still doesn't work, I keep getting the same error